# How can we able to display the duplicate item in Ag-grid Tree data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I able to display the duplicate items in Ag grid Tree data(Ag-enterprise edition)?

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: If you are a customer, you should be able to add this question in zendesk, the official channel for support in ag-grid, we should be able to help you there

Comment: If you want to post it here, you are going to have to add a plunker so that we can have a look

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to make the result from the `getDataPath()` function unique. That will cause all nodes to be rendered. You will then have to modify the renderer function of the grouping column to show the correct display values. See [this plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/VLDTtiLtkWM71qA0k43U/) for an example.

The example is based on the [File Navigator demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/VLDTtiLtkWM71qA0k43U/) from the ag-Grid site. I duplicated the 'notes.txt' entry and gave it a unique ID. Removed the fileName from every entry in the `rowData` list and moved it to a separate object property. Updated the `getDataPath()` function to include the ID for leave nodes. That makes them unique so the grid will show all files. Final step was to use the object's fileName property (if present) in the cell renderer instead of the cell value.